# How to continuously get data from socket and update it in a html table?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, sockets

I'm trying to build a web application where I need to get data continuously from a socket and need to process the data and update it in a HTML table.

I have already asked a question regarding it but had no reply yet. I'm very new to web development. Please help me to solve this problem. You can refer to my previous question:

[How to receive data continuously and update HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029009/how-to-receive-data-continuously-and-update-html-table)

Comment: Please share some code other wise you may not your answer coz nobody write full code for you. It's the place where you find solution.

Comment: I think the way you're setting this up will be very difficult not to lose packets. Would you want to talk in chat? I would love to suggest websockets but they can be a bit intimidating if you're somewhat new to web development.

Comment: A. A. Noman, you can find my code in the link provided in the question. Thank you

Comment: User2027202827, I would like to chat with you but my reputation is not enough to start a chat

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to start a chat with you. The site has prompted it before but I'm not sure how to initiate it. Maybe comment here again when you're back on. If you're not on now, I think I can be back again 7 hours from now.